# C++ Apply function to some elements in a container

Tags: c++, c++11

I would like to apply a function to some elements of an std::vector.I use std::includes to check if a "smaller" vector exists in a "bigger" one, and if exists I would like to apply a function to these elements of the "bigger" vector that are equal to the elements of the "smaller". Any suggestions?

Edit:
<sub>The following was incorrectly posted as an answer by the OP</sub>

There is a problem with std::search! It finds the first occurrence of a sequence contained in a vector while in my vector these elements are in several positions.Also i have a vector of objects!!!

Comment: I'm not sure what difference having a *vector of objects* makes. If define `operator==` for your *object* the code I posted below should work. The standard library also has [`find_end`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/find_end) which will find the last occurrence of a subrange. To find an arbitrary occurrence you could repeatedly call `std::search` after modifying the first argument to the function based on the result of the previous call. If you can use Boost, it offers [`find_nth`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost/algorithm/find_nth.html) which does what you want.

Answer (score 2):

Not sure what part you're having trouble with, but here's a simple example showing the range of elements contained in the larger `vector` that are identical to the contents of the smaller one being multiplied by 2. I used [`std::search`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/search) instead of `std::includes` to determine whether the larger `vector` contains the range of elements in the smaller one because unlike `includes`, which returns a boolean result, `search` will return an iterator to the beginning of the contained range in the larger `vector`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

void times_two(int& t)
{
    t *= 2;
}

int main()
{
    std::vector<int> v1{1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9};
    std::vector<int> v2{4,5,6};

    // find if the larger vector contains the smaller one
    auto first = std::search(v1.begin(), v1.end(), v2.begin(), v2.end());
    if(first != v1.end()) {
        // get the last element in the sub-range
        auto last = std::next(first, v2.size());

        // apply function to each sub-range element
        std::for_each(first, last, times_two);
    }

    for(auto const& v : v1) {
        std::cout << v << ' ';
    }
    std::cout << '\n';
}
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 8 10 12 7 8 9
```

Edit:
[Here's an example](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/58842cadbfa05031) that uses [`boost::find_nth`](http://www.boost.org/doc/html/boost/algorithm/find_nth.html) to perform the search.

Comment: nit, instead of defining your own functor times_two, don't forget about the std's multiplies functor template to do that one for you:   std::transform(first, last, first, std::bind1st(multiplies<int>(),2) );

Comment: @DavidNeiss `[](int i){return 2*i;}` is shorter and more readable (and less deprecated)  than `std::bind1st(std::multiplies<int>(),2)` and the more contemporary `std::bind(std::multiplies<int>(),2,std::placeholders::_1)`.

Comment: Ok, if you have C++11 lambdas available, I can definitely agree with you on that. My suggestion is looking a bit old school, these days.

Comment: @DavidNeiss I intentionally didn't use `std::multiplies` or another function defined by the standard library to demonstrate use of a custom function. Anyway, a lambda is easier on the eyes, if nothing else, than `bind1st` and friends.